# Copy method of case class seems to be missing

Tags: scala, case-class

I'm having trouble understanding why `copy` method is not created/picked up in case class `TestCaseClassStore`.

```scala
abstract class IdStore {
  self =>
  type Entity
  type Ref <: IdRef[_]
  type Self <: IdStore {type Entity = self.Entity; type Ref = self.Ref}

  def copy(data: Map[Ref, Entity]): Self

  def data: Map[Ref, Entity]

  def merge(other: Self): Self = copy(data ++ other.data)
}

trait IdRef[T] {
  def id: T
}

case class IntIdRef(id:Int) extends IdRef[Int]

class TestStore(val data: Map[IntIdRef, Object]) extends IdStore {
  override type Entity = Object
  override type Ref = IntIdRef
  override type Self = TestStore

  override def copy(newData: Map[Ref, Entity]): Self = new TestStore(newData)

  override def toString() = "TestStore(" + data + ")"
}

case class TestCaseClassStore(data: Map[IntIdRef, Object]) extends IdStore {
  override type Entity = Object
  override type Ref = IntIdRef
  override type Self = TestCaseClassStore
}

object Main extends App {
    val data = Map(IntIdRef(1) -> "target 1", IntIdRef(2) -> "target 2"); 

    val classic = new TestStore(data)
    println(classic.copy(classic.data))

    val caseClass = new TestCaseClassStore(data)
    println(caseClass.copy(caseClass.data))
}
```

This ends up with undefined method error:

```
Main.scala:30: error: class TestCaseClassStore needs to be abstract, since method copy in class IdStore of type (data: Map[TestCaseClassStore.this.Ref,TestCaseClassStore.this.Entity])TestCaseClassStore.this.Self is not defined
case class TestCaseClassStore(data: Map[IntIdRef, Object]) extends IdStore {
           ^
one error found
```

If I add a following line to the case class it works, but it is quite useless, because the main reason I wanted to use a case class was the auto-generated copy method.

```
  override def copy(newData: Map[Ref, Entity]): Self = TestCaseClassStore(newData)
```

---

- Why isn't `copy` method present on `TestCaseClassStore`? Perhaps a limitation of a compiler or the language? Or did I implement incorrectly the super class (but `TestStore` class is working)?
- Is there some **terse** way of writing more implementations of `IdStore` (preferably without repeating `copy` method, or even somehow abstracting `Entity` and `Ref` types in constructor so they are mentioned only once in type definition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not generate a copy-method if there is one already present.

You can see that by adding an implementation to the copy-method in the super class, it won't get overwritten. I suspect this is intentional.

Comment: intentional, see http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes

Comment: So even though `copy` in `IdStore` is abstract, it is still considered being present and generation is skipped :-(. Thank you for clarification.